How to run a shell script from a shell script so that previously exported variables are not available?
Scenario:
$ cat t42.sh
source t42a.sh
bash t42b.sh

$ cat t42a.sh
export x="y"

$ cat t42b.sh
echo $x

$ bash t42.sh
y

I need to somehow run t42b.sh from t42.sh in a "clean environment", so that x is not available in t42b.sh.
Is this possible at all (w/o unset / export -n)? If so, then how?

It uses unset, but all you need to do is execute t42b.sh in a subshell that uses unset. (unset x; bash t42b.sh).


I need to somehow run t42b.sh from t42.sh so that x is not available
in t42b.sh.
Is this possible at all (w/o unset / export -n)? If so, then how?

Yes, you can do this without modifying the environment from which t42b.sh is launched.  There are several ways, but one of the easier and more portable is to run t42b.sh via the env command:

env — set the environment for command invocation

Your most portable option with env is to start with an empty environment and add the environment variables that the script you are launching should have (warning: there may be more of these than you think).  This would be something like:
env -i PATH=$PATH USER=$USER HOME=$HOME t42b.sh

With GNU env, however, and maybe others, you also have the alternative of using env to unset specific variables for the command to be launched, maybe something like this:
env -u x t42b.sh


If it would be satisfactory for x to be defined to a null value in t42b.sh, as opposed to being undefined altogether, then there's an easier way: just define it to nothing on t42b.sh's command line:
x= t42b.sh

# or, equivalently:

x='' t42b.sh


If in case of -i "the inherited environment shall be ignored completely", then why env -i bash -c "echo $PATH" prints non-empty string? Does it mean that PATH does not belong to the inherited environment?

@pmor, because in that particular command, the $PATH is expanded by the shell in which the env command is executed, not in the one launched by env.  But if you changed the quotes to single instead of double, you would likely find that bash itself provides a minimal default path (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin for me) if it does not inherit one.

You can remove variables from environment with env:
env -u x bash t42b.sh


You can execute your t42b.sh script with env -i:
env -i PATH="$PATH" bash t42b.sh

as per man env:

-i Execute the utility with only those environment variables specified by name=value options.  The environment inherited by env is ignored completely.


FYI: On Cygwin env -i bash t42b.sh produces env: ‘bash’: No such file or directory. The env has version 9.0.

Any ideas how to fix the env: ‘bash’: No such file or directory on Cygwin?

I don't have cygwin but tested it on Linux and Mac and worked fine on both the systems.

It seems that the solution is env -i PATH="$PATH" bash t42b.sh.

Oh ok that's great. I have updated my answer to reflect that.
